# Transform string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How would you do this...?

I am trying to write a string transformer, which capitalises certain letter in string.

Examples

```
lorem lipum lampum => lorem Lipum lampum
popud pidem papusek => popud pidem Papusek
```

Thanks!

Comment: it's hard to figure out what the rules for capitalisation are ? :O

Comment: “certain letter in string”: which letters? All `Li` s? All `Pa` s? Every second, third word?

Comment: @Marcel It could be third, second, or whatever. It depends on passed argument.

Comment: Which “passed argument”? There's nothing about an argument in your question. What are the values that argument can take and how does it influence the capitalization algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should randomly capitalize every fifth string:

```
var s = "lorem lipum lampum";
var a = s.split(" ");
for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
 if (Math.random() > 0.2) {
  a[i] = a[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a[i].substring(1);
  }
 }
s = a.join(" ");
```

Here's an update now that you clarified:

```
var doIt = function (s, which) {
  var a = s.split(" ");
  a[which] = a[which].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a[which].substring(1);
  return a.join(" ");
 }
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can get the pattern definitively set, use Regex to find the pieces that need capitalizing. If you are using a dictionary, a state machine pattern is the best. For easy coding, the fastest is running through the words one at a time and finding those that fit the pattern. If perf is the main need, there are tricky ways to increase perf, including (at the extreme end) using binary.

Comment: A regex is a bit of a heavy tool for this job. See Rob's answer how one can achieve this more efficiently.

Comment: Not sure I agree, but JavaScript may not be the best Regex langauge. :-)

Comment: Then why do you propose to use a regular expression? ;-)